# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Here is my `Routes.php`

```
Route::get('invitation/{id}/{query_string}' , 'Invitationscontroller@invitation_link');
```

Here is my `Invitationscontroller.php`

```
public function invitation_link(){
        return "Hello";
    }
```

When I hit this URL `example.com/invitation/1/exUgWa0apsAmeAzyBLruYvR0S6WqtYBH`

I get error as

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Where m I lacking?

Any help would be grateful.
Thank You.

Comment: did you pass id and query string

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned URL above.

Comment: When you are loading the page, did you pass id and a query string in the browser's url

Comment: Yes... It is passed already when the page loads with above URL.

Comment: look your routing table hitting this command in the command prompt.

Comment: php artisan route:list

Comment: Yes... it is there in routing table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117171/discussion-between-dulaj-sanjaya-and-bhavin-shah).

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this kind of problems by issuing theese commands to clear cache and regenerate autoload files:

```
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

EDIT

If you use Apache:

- check your apache configuration and allow .htaccess override
- enable mod_rewrite
- check your .htaccess file to be the same provided by Laravel

Comment: Actually , this is the only route that i  can't access. other routes path, I can access easily.

Answer (score 0):

open `/public/index.php` then change `$app->run();` to `$app->run($app['request']);`

that will work.